# No headers or source files in QT creator

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I'm having a problem with creating new header and source files in QT. I can only add new files to the build, it's grayed for the "main" project as you can see below.

[image]

I can create them specifically for the build and they only appear once in the documents area. There is no header tree branch. After I close qt I have to create new ones. I want them to appear in the tree and be connected with the main project. I have "hide source and headers files" option off.

[image]

I've obviously tried creating them the way it was shown on the yt. I've searched through settings but didn't found anything I could use.

Comment: This is the norm for CMake projects.  You have to create a new (header, source, class) file and manually add it in CMake.

Comment: could you elaborate more on that? I've found some instructions about adding those lines: For a header file: include_directories(path/to/header/file)
For a source file: add_executable(executable_name path/to/source/file)  Is that it? Do I have to do that with every project I do?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add the files manually in CMake.

1. Go to **File>New File** and select what type of file you want.  Typically it will be a source, header, or both (class).
2. Edit the CMakeLists.txt file:

```
      qt_add_executable(myapp
            myapp.qrc
            main.cpp
            new_file.cpp
            new_file.h

    )
```

Resources like *.qml* files and things like images (**.png *.jpg*) are added in the *myapp.qrc* file